# Connection timeout on cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've got a Laravel app I'm trying to migrate to Google Cloud. I've already got it setup on App Engine but whenever I try to access it any non-static page which requires a DB connection the app throws up the following error:

> 2017-08-02 10:21:18,983 INFO     **_FILE_ONLY_** 2017-08-02 08:21:12
>   default[20170802t095328]  [02-Aug-2017 08:21:12] WARNING: [pool app]
>   child 62 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: [2017-08-02 08:21:12]
>   production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   timed out in
>   /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43"
>
> 2017-08-02 10:21:18,984 INFO     **_FILE_ONLY_** 2017-08-02 08:21:12
>   default[20170802t095328]  [02-Aug-2017 08:21:12] WARNING: [pool app]
>   child 62 said into stderr: "Stack trace:"
>
> 2017-08-02 10:21:18,986 INFO     **_FILE_ONLY_** 2017-08-02 08:21:12
>   default[20170802t095328]  [02-Aug-2017 08:21:12] WARNING: [pool app]
>   child 62 said into stderr: "#0
>   /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=35.1...', 'my_db_user', 'my_db_pass',
>   Array)"

Any help in resolving it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/
When connecting from App Engine you shouldn't be connecting using the IP

Comment: Thanks @Vadim. Much appreciated. We're actually on the flexible plan but I imagine the same rules apply. The relevant snippet of our app.yml looks thus

 `## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: 35.1**.***.**
  DB_DATABASE: <db_name>
  DB_USERNAME: <db_user>
  DB_PASSWORD: <db_pass>
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/<sql_instance>`

If I understand correctly I should remove those entries and replace them with

`MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<sql_instance>;dbname=<db_name>
  MYSQL_USER: 
  MYSQL_PASSWORD:`

Yes?

Comment: So I tried your suggestion above and got an outright "Connection refused" error and the logs indicated the app was trying to connect on localhost. Weird.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql#setting_connection_strings_and_adding_a_library
Please go through the steps in the doc and you have setup everything as expected. for GAE Flex you also have to specify cloud_sql_instances in your app config.

Comment: @Vadim: thank you. I found out what the problem was. I was missing the unix_socket section below in my config/databases.php file:

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    //gcloud
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],