# How to connect to Google cloud SQL instance using php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-sql

With the following code am able to connect to my SQL instance from localhost environment , but when i upload the same code to my VM instance and try to connect it from there am getting "connection failed: connection timed out"

Note: I added VM instance's External IP address in Authorized network section.

```
<?php
$servername = "SQL INSTANCE IP ADDRESS : port";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname="appdb";

$response=array();

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: External IP address? That sounds wrong, because databases are usually not exposed to the public internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect and retrieve data from Google Cloud SQL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340559/how-do-i-connect-and-retrieve-data-from-google-cloud-sql-using-php)

Comment: Then how do we make connection to sql instance from VM instance?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI thats what i did , but am still getting connection timed out

Comment: what about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456250/connection-timeout-on-cloud-sql

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Thanks, we should use sql instance name to connect to sql instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your PHP outside of GCP (compute VM, App Engine, etc) You can either Install the [cloud proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) in your app server and your app would connect like if the DB was in localhost, or you can use the [public IP settings](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) (I would suggest using the Proxy this way you don't have to use attach a public IP to your SQL instance)

If the PHP app is hosted in GCP you may follow the steps for [the service](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) where your app is

Answer (score 0):

## How to connect from Compute Engine to Cloud SQL internal ip address (PHP)

> Your Compute Engine instance must be in the same region as your Cloud
>   SQL instance, and on the network configured for a private connection

1.[Create the Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance) instance with internal ip address . Create a user, password and database.

2.[Getting started with PHP on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine)

After you copied the `startup-script.sh` runt this command to create the instance:

```
 gcloud compute instances create $MY_INSTANCE_NAME \
--image-family=ubuntu-1804-lts \
--image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
--machine-type=g1-small \
--scopes userinfo-email,cloud-platform,sql-admin  \
--metadata-from-file startup-script=scripts/startup-script.sh \
--zone $ZONE \
--tags http-server
```

On the scopes we added `sql-admin`, then create the firewall rule.

3.SSH to the instance you just created.

4.Install `mysql`. You could add this part to the startup script.

```
 sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7
```

5.Test if you can connect to SQL instance using internal ip address.

```
mysql --host=internall-ip-sql  --user=test --password
```

6.If you are able to connect then :

```
cd /opt/app/routes
sudo nano web.php
```

7.Add your code to `router->get('/', function (Request $request)`

8.In the browser go to http://compute-engine-instance-externall-ip

Success!